# Define variable as member of c union?

Tags: c, struct, unions

I am working on a large project which was written by someone else. There is a global general purpose buffer that is reused in many places of the project. I want to add some code that will use this buffer but I want to use a struct, typically I would use a union for this, i.e.

```
typedef union StructuredBuffer {
    MessageStructure message;
    uint8_t bytes[BUFFER_SIZE];
} StructuredBuffer;

StructuredBuffer structuredBuffer;
```

and access the struct with: `structuredlBuffer.message.structMember ...`

and the raw buffer with: `structuredBuffer.bytes ...`

The issue I have is that `generalBuffer` is already used in lots of different places and I don't want to change all that code to use `generalBuffer.bytes` (instead of `generalBuffer`), is there a way I can change the definition of `generalBuffer` to "point" to `structuredBuffer.bytes` so that I can use the memory of general buffer as a union but the rest of the project can use it as it currently does?

(when I say "point" I know this is the wrong word as I don't want a pointer that needs to be dereferenced, but I'm not sure what else to call it)

Comment: Some IDE's have the possibility to rename variables or symbols across the project. What environment are you working in?

Comment: How is `generalBuffer` declared now?

Comment: @ScottHunter It is currently declared as `uint8_t generalBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];`

Comment: Hmm, `StructuredBuffer structuredBuffer` --> naming that differs only in case is less clear than names that differ in characters.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm working in Microchip Studio, I think it has that functionality but the effort of renaming isn't the issue, it's that it confuses the rest of the project for others who just need to use `generalBuffer` as a plain buffer

Comment: Dunno about that name, looks more like a UnionedBuffer to me than a StructuredBuffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your union is the right solution, I'd break the code and fix all the things that fail to compile.  It's safe, relatively quick, the right thing to do and totally reliable that you've addressed all references.  Do it on a Friday afternoon or sometime when you don't want to think too hard but have to be "working".

If your IDE can do it for you then so much the better.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer since it is the most correct way if others have this same niche issue. However I don't want to change otherwise unrelated parts of the project which others may work on and still expect generalBuffer to still be a simple buffer so will instead be using `MessageStructure* message = (MessageStructure*) &generalBuffer[0];` and `message->structMember` to access members. As Ian Abbott pointed out in the comments of another answer this could cause alignment issues but I am working with an 8-bit system so should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good use case for a macro.

So in the header file where `generalBuffer` is used, add this after the declaration:

```
extern uint8_t generalBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
#define generalBuffer structuredBuffer.bytes
```

And in the .c file where it's actually defined, be sure to `#undef generalBuffer` right before that.

Alternately, you can change the definition of `generalBuffer` to be a pointer to `structuredBuffer`.

```
uint8_t *generalBuffer = &structuredBuffer.bytes[0];
```

Comment: Thanks I think a macro might be the way to go, your alternative has also given me the idea to instead use the structure by pointing at the buffer i.e. `MessageStructure* message = (MessageStructure*) &generalBuffer;` that way the rest of the project is truely unaffected by my changes.

Comment: Re “This sounds like a good use case for a macro”: It is a mediocre use case for a macro; using a macro is a kludge that is perhaps appropriate for a dead-end project you need to keep alive a little while longer. In that case, the kludge will not be too badly compounded by further kludges before the project is dead. For a healthy ongoing project, updating the code per [LoztInSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1166774/loztinspace)’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77654142/298225) is the better solution.

Comment: Wouldn't that need a `extern StructuredBuffer structuredBuffer;` in the header?

Comment: @drdoof `MessageStructure* message = (MessageStructure*) &generalBuffer;` might not be properly aligned, leading to UB.

Comment: Why keep the `extern uint8_t generalBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];` declaration in the header when the variable no longer exists?

Comment: Changing `generalBuffer` to a pointer is not without risk.  The change would be visible in a few ways, such as in code that computes `sizeof generalBuffer` or takes its address.

Comment: It depends on which version you choose, @Gerhardh.  The macro alternative would indeed require an extern declaration of the union object (and a definition of its type, too).  The pointer version, not.

Comment: @IanAbbott Good spot, although luckily for me as this code will be compiled for an 8-bit system there will be no padding added to the structure so I should be able to safely use my solution. I didn't know about alignment previously so I will keep an eye out for if it is an issue.

Comment: @drdoof, it may be that none of your implementation's types have an alignment requirement greater than one byte, but I don't take that as necessarily following from the target being an 8-bit system.

Comment: I suggest adding an extra `const` to declaration of `generalBuffer` to let the compiler generate better code. I mean `uint8_t * const generalBuffer = ...`